# Rename files adding their parent folder name

Tags: command-line, scripts, software-recommendation

I want to rename file name with its parent folder name, *adding* the folder name before the current name.

for example:

Folder structure

```
SOCH NC KT 633-ROYAL BLUE-MULTI
|
| 1.jpg
|
| 2.jpg
|
| 3.jpg
```

Expected Result

```
SOCH NC KT 633-ROYAL BLUE-MULTI
|
|_SOCH NC KT 633-ROYAL BLUE-MULTI1.jpg
|
|_SOCH NC KT 633-ROYAL BLUE-MULTI2.jpg
|
|_SOCH NC KT 633-ROYAL BLUE-MULTI3.jpg

SOCH NC KT 710-BLACK-MULTI
```

Could anyone advise how this can be done in a .sh file? Is there any utility is available to do the operation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a small python script, renaming files *recursively* (folders as well as sub folders):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import shutil
import os
import sys

dr = sys.argv[1]

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dr):
    for f in files:
        shutil.move(root+"/"+f, root+"/"+root.split("/")[-1]+f)
```

#### How to use

- Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `rename_files.py`
- Run it with the directory as an argument:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/rename_files.py /directory/with/files
  ```

#### Note

As always, first try on a sample!

#### Explanation

The script:

- Walks through the directories, looking for files.
- If files are found, it splits the path to the file with the delimiter "/", keeping the last in the row (which is the parent's folder name) , to be pasted before the file's name:

  ```py
  root.split("/")[-1]
  ```
- Subsequently, move the file to the renamed one:

  ```py
  shutil.move(root+"/"+f, root+"/"+root.split("/")[-1]+f)
  ```

Comment: @JacobVlijm the same can aswell be done in bash with `for F in *; do cd $F; for D in *; do mv -Tv $D $F$D; done; cd ..; done`.  Just mentioning so you can add it to your answer as another possible solution given youre in the parent directory where the directories reside which you want to work down.

Comment: @Videonauth thanks, but the command doesn't really work as expected :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm weird, i tested it before i posted it and it did its job. i made a folder test with two foldesr a nd b inside it, switched into the test folder, created in a and b files with touch(just to test) and the command renamed each file to have the foldername in fron of the filename in both folders.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with `rename`:

```bsh
rename -n 's/(.*)\//$1\/$1/' */*
```

This command needs to be started in the directory directly above the directories you want to process. It will first only list the changes for you to check, if you're happy with the results run it without `-n` to perform the renaming.

#### Example run

```
$ tree
.
└── SOCH NC KT 633-ROYAL BLUE-MULTI
    ├── 1.jpg
    ├── 2.jpg
    └── 3.jpg
$ rename 's/(.*)\//$1\/$1/' */*
$ tree
.
└── SOCH NC KT 633-ROYAL BLUE-MULTI
    ├── SOCH NC KT 633-ROYAL BLUE-MULTI1.jpg
    ├── SOCH NC KT 633-ROYAL BLUE-MULTI2.jpg
    └── SOCH NC KT 633-ROYAL BLUE-MULTI3.jpg
```

#### Explanation

```bsh
rename 's/(.*)\//$1\/$1/' */*
```

- `s/a/b/` – `s`ubstitute `a` by `b`
- `(.*)\/` – take everything until (excl.) the last slash saving it as group 1 
  *and substitute it by*
- `$1\/$1` – group 1 (dir name), a slash and group 1 again (file name prefix)

Comment: If you get an error "Argument list too long", you can use `find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type f -exec rename -n 's/(.*)\//$1\/$1/' {} \;` instead. This is adapted from https://askubuntu.com/a/1081902/301745

Comment: Personally I'd write the Perl expression with a different delimiter like `|` (pipe), to avoid escaping slashes: `'s|(.*)/|$1/$1|'`

Answer (score 4):

Using only shell (`bash`) with a little help from `mv`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar  ##globstar will let us match files recursively
files=( /foo/bar/**/*.jpg )  ##Array containing matched files, mention where to search and what files here
for i in "${files[@]}"; do 
    d="${i%/*}"  ##Parameter expansion, gets the path upto the parent directory
    d_="${d##*/}"  ##gets the name of parent directory
    f="${i##*/}"  ##gets the file name
        echo mv "$i" "$d"/"${d_}""$f"  ##renaming, remove echo after confirming what will be changed and you are good
done
```

**Example:**

```
$ shopt -s globstar
$ files=( /foo/bar/**/*.jpg )
$ for i in "${files[@]}"; do d="${i%/*}"; d_="${d##*/}"; f="${i##*/}"; echo mv "$i" "$d"/"${d_}""$f"; done
mv /foo/bar/KT/633-ROYAL/4.jpg /foo/bar/KT/633-ROYAL/633-ROYAL4.jpg
mv /foo/bar/KT/633-ROYAL/5.jpg /foo/bar/KT/633-ROYAL/633-ROYAL5.jpg
mv /foo/bar/KT/633-ROYAL/6.jpg /foo/bar/KT/633-ROYAL/633-ROYAL6.jpg
mv /foo/bar/KT/633-ROYAL/BLUE-MULTI/1.jpg /foo/bar/KT/633-ROYAL/BLUE-MULTI/BLUE-MULTI1.jpg
mv /foo/bar/KT/633-ROYAL/BLUE-MULTI/2.jpg /foo/bar/KT/633-ROYAL/BLUE-MULTI/BLUE-MULTI2.jpg
mv /foo/bar/KT/633-ROYAL/BLUE-MULTI/3.jpg /foo/bar/KT/633-ROYAL/BLUE-MULTI/BLUE-MULTI3.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Bash solution, executing from folder where filenames you want to change are placed. You have to change `workdir` to your path

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar

workdir="/path/to/your/dir"

for folder in $workdir/**/*;do
  if [[ -d "$folder" ]]; then
    for file in "$folder"/*;do
        if [[ -f "$file" ]]; then
            fi="`basename "$file"`"
            fo="`basename "$folder"`"
            mv "$file" "$folder/$fo$fi"
        fi
    done
  fi
done
```

It will change **all files** in **all directories** recursively from your workdir .

Comment: You could enable nullglob (`shopt -s nullglob`) and use a dir-only glob (`"$workdir"/**/`) to get rid of `if [[ -d "$folder" ]] ...`. Also note that you should always quote variables like `$workdir`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small example of how that can be done form the directory you want to edit.

```
$> ls                                                                          
file1.txt  file2.txt  file3.txt
$> pwd
/home/xieerqi/testing_dir
$> find . -type f -printf "%f\0" | \                                           
> while IFS="" read -d "" filename ; do \                                      
> echo $filename ${PWD##*/}_$filename   ; done
file2.txt testing_dir_file2.txt
file1.txt testing_dir_file1.txt
file3.txt testing_dir_file3.txt
```

Replace `echo` with `mv` or `cp` for copying or moving as necessary

Answer (score 0):

Yet another bash-only approach, to be executed in the folder where the files that need renaming reside:

`for f in * ;  do mv "$f" "$(basename "$(pwd)")"_"$f" ;  done`

This will also handle file and folder names with spaces.