# Rename files by adding their parent folder name

Tags: command-line, rename

I have a parent directory composed of a set of sub-directories. Each sub-directory is composed of a list of files.

Here is the scenario:

```
v_1:
filenames.txt

v_2:
labels.txt

v_3:
coding.txt
```

What is my expected output?

```
v_1:
v_1_filenames.txt

v_2:
v_2_labels.txt

v_3:
v_3_coding.txt
```

**What l have tried to solve that?**

```
rename -n 's/(.*)\//$1\/$1_/' */*
```

which prints

```
rename(v_1/filenames.txt, v_1/v_1_filenames.txt)
rename(v_2/labels.txt, v_2/v_2_labels.txt)
rename(v_3/coding.txt, v_3/v_3_coding.txt)
```

However it doesn't work. To confirm that I did:

```
ls *
```

and I get:

```
v_1:
filenames.txt

v_2:
labels.txt

v_3:
coding.txt
```

Any cue? Thank you

Comment: Re the duplicate, see [dessert's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1003784/301745) specifically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply remove the option `-n`. From [`man prename`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/prename.1.html)*:

```
-n, --no-act
        No Action: show what files would have been renamed.
```

* There are multiple commands called `rename`; I assume you're using `prename` on Ubuntu 16.04 or earlier, though option `-n` does the same thing for most other versions. For details see [What's the difference between the different "rename" commands?](https://askubuntu.com/q/956010/301745)

Comment: Thank you for your answer @wjandrea. I tested it but it doesn't work for large directories. I have 13,000 sub-directories each contain about 300 files. So l tried ls | xargs rename 's/(.*)\//$1\/$1_/' */*
and l still get -bash: /usr/bin/xargs: Argument list too long

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081884/bash-usr-bin-rename-argument-list-too-long