# "-bash: /usr/bin/rename: Argument list too long"

Tags: command-line, xargs

I would like to rename files within each sub-directory by adding the name of the sub-directory. Following the answer from [Rename files by adding their parent folder name](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081752/rename-files-by-adding-their-parent-folder-name?noredirect=1#comment1777904_1081752), I tried:

```
rename  's/(.*)\//$1\/$1_/' */*
```

However for lots of sub-directories it doesn't work. I have 13,000 sub-directories each containing about 300 files. I get

```
-bash: /usr/bin/rename:  Argument list too long
```

I tried:

```
ls | xargs rename 's/(.*)\//$1\/$1_/' */*
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs rename 's/(.*)\//$1\/$1_/' */*
```

Both give the same error:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/xargs:  Argument list too long
```

**EDIT**

```
xargs -L  rename 's/(.*)\//$1\/$1_/' */*
xargs -L1  rename 's/(.*)\//$1\/$1_/' */*
```

Same error:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/xargs:  Argument list too long
```

Comment: An unquoted `*/*` is always expanded by the shell; if you have too many matching files then it'll always be an "Argument list too long" even before `xargs` could get to do its business. The point of `xargs` is that it reads the list of files from stdin _instead of_ parameters, that is, you should _not_ have a final `*/*`. The `ls` or `find` command is supposed to list the filenames.

Comment: @Melebius, l get the same message -bash: /usr/bin/xargs: Argument list too long either with -L1 or L

Comment: @Melebius, please see me edit

Comment: See the linked duplicate. When dealing with argument list too long error you either have to use `find` with `-exec` flag or a for loop.

Answer (score 6):

As [@egmont noted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081884/bash-usr-bin-rename-argument-list-too-long?noredirect=1#comment1778054_1081884), giving the paths (`*/*`) as argument(s) to [`xargs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) is wrong. This command reads file names from the standard input instead of arguments, so issuing `xargs` *without* any standard input (the EDIT section of the question) is useless.

### Solution using `ls` and `xargs`

Check if you can just `ls` all the paths in question.

```
ls */*
```

If yes, you can use a corrected version of your 2) option:

```
ls */* | xargs rename -n 's/(.*)\//$1\/$1_/'
```

## Solution using `find`

If you get an error from the `ls` call, you can still use `find`.

1. This command has an `-exec` option which works similarly to `xargs`, so we’ll not need `xargs` in this case at all.
2. To mimic the behavior of `ls */*`, use the options `-mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2`.

The corrected version of the 3) option would be:

```
find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type f -exec rename -n 's/(.*)\//$1\/$1_/' {} \;
```

The argument placeholder together with an escaped semicolon (`{} \;`) ensures that `rename` is run just for a single file at a time, similarly to `xargs -L1`. This will prevent the original issue with too many files at once.

### Dry run and actual rename

You can check the result using the `-n` option I included after `rename` to just list the renames it would do. To actually launch the rename operation, [remove the `-n` option](https://askubuntu.com/a/1081763/250300).

Comment: I think he wants `-mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2`, which would be the equivalent to `*/*`.

Comment: @Melebius, as mentionned in the top of my post details are described in  Rename files by adding their parent folder name

Comment: @Melebius. It seems to work  it's still running. I let you know

Comment: @Rovo you are write find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -exec rename -n 's/(.*)\//$1\/$1_/' {} \; describes my need

Comment: @Josselin Were you satisfied with my answer? Then please give me an upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, it would be nice if you [accepted](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) my answer (✓). In the opposite case, please clarify your needs using [edit]ing or comments. https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers